# Laravel invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

having an issue with this function.

It's a function to call a python script based on the parameters $a and $c in another function.

It's the foreach() inside the foreach at the bottom that's throwing the error i believe?

Not sure where i'm going wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the error message to your question. And what is `enc.py` doing?

Comment: check your array var_dump($search) see if its multidimensional,

Comment: `$i` is the key, you probably won't be able to iterate it since you should have a collection, an array, or other entity like those.

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi i get:  array:1 [▼
  0 => "aGlkZlxoZWlkwo_ClsKawppnX2hoaWRcZGZkZw=="
] with var_dump (dd in laravel)

Comment: you cant iterate it twice then since after first iteration.

Comment: `$msql = DB::select($query);` should be `$msql = DB::select($query)->get();` I guess.

Comment: And you should not close your first foreach there since the variables such as `$as` is used out of the current scope.